# laptop battery drains while shutdown

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, shutdown

When I shut down(not sleep or standby or hibernate) the computer the is at 80%. Next morning I tried open my laptop it didn't start without plugging the ac power because the battery level is 0%. I'm sure its not my battery problem because its giving 3 hours of backup on 80%(battery life cycle extension) only and I calibrated my battery too.

I bought my laptop last year. My laptop is Samsung series 3 np350v5c Windows 7 home premium 64-bit and 8 gb ram installed. I just wanna know why this happened and a solution of course.

Comment: Don’t ever let it discharge to 0%. Repeatedly doing so will lead to excessive capacity loss.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a loose connection, either at the DC plug or the wall plug.

Does your transformer feel warm? If not, it's not powered on, so there's probably a loose connection at the wall plug (or possibly a dead transformer).

Does the battery feel warm? If not, it's not getting any juice to charge.

Both components will be noticeably warm when operational.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be some hardware drawing power when the laptop is powered down. Common bits of hardware that do this are USB mice and keyboards and in-built wireless network cards.

A few things to check:

1) When you are powered down, is the mouse still active?

```
2) Open Device Manager
* For each hardware listed, open Properties
* Is there a `Power Management` tab?
* If yes, ensure `Allow this device to wake the computer` is NOT selected
* Click Ok (and move onto next hardware entry)
```

For the 2nd step, there will likely be several dozen hardware entries in Device Manager. Each check takes about 15s, so you'll need to budget about 5 or more minutes...be patient!

Another problem may be the network card itself. Modern network cards, by default, continue to draw power even when the laptop is "off". Refer to this [Superuser question and answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1066619/what-is-a-magic-packet-for-waking-a-computer) for details.